# Using before_request in Flask with Blueprints

Tags: python, flask

I looked for this in multiple questions but doesn't seem to have a complete response that works for me.

before_request is not getting run

Here is an overview of my files structure:

MY_APP

> run.py
>   (app)
>
> > __init __.py
> >     models.py
> >     (main)
> >
> > > __init __.py
> > >       views.py

app/__init __.py:
(I'm not including all the includes and Flask initialization to keep it clear)

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint, url_prefix='/')
```

app/main/views.py:

```
@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
    return render_template('main/index.html')
```

And here is my function before_request:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    #load interface variables based on language
```

Am I doing it wrong? as I tried before_app_request.

Comment: Please clearly state `What is not working?`

Comment: I can't fire the before_request

Comment: I tried calling the function from the blueprint as: `mail_blueprint(before_request_func)` and that didn't work as I needed a flask.session inside my function

Comment: I'm not sure why while trying to reproduce it I ended up with making it work. I'm posting an answer with the example (that is working)